# How to correctly free resources allocated by SDL_ttf?

Tags: c, free, sdl-2

I followed the advices in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527414/how-to-load-file-font-into-ram-using-c-c-and-sdl2/) and solved a problem of loading a file into memory. However, I found a problem when I free the resources. If I try to free the `TTF_Font` file before freeing the structure which holds it, the program crashes.

I believe it occurs because double `Free()`. `Free()` twice results undefined behaviour.

Accordingly to the documentation, `TTF_CloseFont` frees **BOTH** font pointer and the font itself. I suspected that when this occurs, the `SDL_RWclose` would free an already freed pointer, so it crashes. But when `SDL_RWclose` frees one of the resources freed by `TTF_CloseFont`, the font itself, it does not occurs. Another indication to me of undefined behaviour

More info: the order which the `ptr_mem_buff` (where the font is stored) is freed does not affect the crash (in my environment).

Also, set the pointers to `nullptr` should have solved, as `free(nullptr)` results nothing. But the program still crashes even after setting the `ptr_Font` to null after `TTF_CloseFont(ptr_Font);`

How should I correctly free these resources?

**Code snippet:**

```
    ptr_str_rwops = SDL_RWFromFile("IMG/FreeMono.ttf", "rb");
        var_size_of_file = SDL_RWsize(ptr_str_rwops);
        ptr_mem_buff = calloc(1, var_size_of_file);
        SDL_RWread(ptr_str_rwops, ptr_mem_buff, 1, var_size_of_file);
        SDL_RWclose(ptr_str_rwops);

    ptr_str_rwops2 = SDL_RWFromConstMem(ptr_mem_buff, var_size_of_file);
        ptr_Font = TTF_OpenFontRW(ptr_str_rwops2, 1, 72);
            ptr_Superficie_texto = TTF_RenderText_Solid(ptr_Font, "Hello World", str_SDL_colour);

    /*CUT UNRELATED CODE*/

//  Example 1:  works fine (in my environment, but I suspect undefined behaviour)
    SDL_RWclose(ptr_str_rwops2);
    free(ptr_mem_buff);
    TTF_CloseFont(ptr_Font);

//  Example 2: crashes everytime, I believe exist double Free()

    TTF_CloseFont(ptr_Font);
    SDL_RWclose(ptr_str_rwops2);
    free(ptr_mem_buff);

// Another approach:

    TTF_CloseFont(ptr_Font);
    ptr_Font = nullptr;
    SDL_RWclose(ptr_str_rwops2); // still crashes
    free(ptr_mem_buff);
```

Comment: You're passing `1` to `TTF_OpenFontRW`, which indicates that it will automatically close and free the source. I imagine you should either pass `0` and manually close/free `ptr_str_rwops2`, or pass `1` and do not manually close/free `ptr_str_rwops2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call

`ptr_Font = TTF_OpenFontRW(ptr_str_rwops2, 1, 72);`

tells TTF to dispose of the RWOps stream (that's what the 1 means). You don't have to close that stream because the call to `TTF_CloseFont()` will do that. You **DO** have to free the `ptr_mem_buff` though, because the RWOps stream will not do that.